# Synchronizing repositories with Git

Tags: git

i and a friend are developing a web application and using Git for versioning. In the office we are using a model of a central repository and also, each developer has your personal repository. I and my friend are working from house now, and i have implemented features that my friend needs. How i can send a resume of my commits to my friend, in such way that he can be aware of my improvements? Detail: I'm with more commits than my friend and i don't know at what point ours branchs diverge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some kind of public repository, don't you? If not, run

```
git daemon
```

Your friend can then pull your repository into a new branch, see what's changed and eventually merge:

```
git checkout -b lucas
git pull git://lucascomputer/
git checkout master
git diff lucas
git merge lucas
```

Comment: Have you considered using http://github.com as your public repository? You can easily send pull requests there.

Comment: The problem is that the repository contains a commercial software that we are developing and the bussiness that we working don't have a repository that we can use from house ...

Answer (score 1):

You could do a git push to his repository. The syntax of **git push** is:

```
git push [remote-repository-reference] [remote-head-name]
```

So assuming that the remote repository is named **origin** and the remote head name is **master** the command would be:

```
git push origin master
```

Executing the above command does two things:

- Add new commit objects sent by the pushing repository.
- Set [remote-head-name] to point to the same commit that it 
  points to on the pushing repository.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your friend should run "git checkout HEAD" afterwards, or he won't see your changes. See http://hans.fugal.net/blog/2008/11/10/git-push-is-worse-than-worthless/